# Adding Time Stamp Values in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a SSRS Report and am facing a problem in some calculation.

I have few columns that contains the values like 101.45, 25, 0.15, 3.30.

Actually these values are time values, now adding all these leads to the result 129.9.

Now the problem is when the decimal part exceeds .60 I need to add one to number, like the final result I need is 130.30.

Can any one please help me solving this problem.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add the values directly. You need to first convert the values into scale of 100. Add it and then convert it back to your scale of 60.

```
SELECT SUM(Floor(Column1)+(Column1%1)*100/60) FROM TimeAdd
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5d55/8

For doing this in SSRS

```
=
(Int(ReportItems!TextBox1.Value) + (ReportItems!TextBox1.Value Mod 1)*100/60)
+
(Int(ReportItems!TextBox2.Value) + (ReportItems!TextBox2.Value Mod 1)*100/60)
+
(Int(ReportItems!TextBox3.Value) + (ReportItems!TextBox3.Value Mod 1)*100/60)
+
(Int(ReportItems!TextBox4.Value) + (ReportItems!TextBox4.Value Mod 1)*100/60)
```

But the above will give you 130.5 but you would probably want 130.3. You need to convert the above sum back into scale of 60. either you can store everything in another variable and then apply the scaling or write a big piece of code.

```
=INT(ReportItems!AbsoluteSum.Value) + (ReportItems!AbsoluteSum.Value Mod 1)*60/100
```

Just a suggestion It is easier to solve something in SQL then in report design.

Comment: But these values are in different different columns, and i need solution to be use in SSRS Reports.
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Please see my updated response. Also you can do the same thing in SSRS expression.

Comment: @DadapeerPvg I made few more edits please see my updated response.

Comment: As u suggest, i Solve this in SQL than in Report Design. ThanQ :) @Anup Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom fields in your dataset where you can write expression which convert your time value to some integer value, or decimal value.

This process you need repeat for all fields from database that participate in your calculation, where finally in your dataset you have let's say, seven standard columns from database, and seven custom columns, which you can later working with.

Other solution could be writing some custom code in SSRS, where you can create function, which accepts parameters, and do calculations for you.